# Calculate percentage in Excel pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot, percentage

I have an Excel table with country, ID & group columns.
I created a pivot table with countries in rows, groups in columns and 
the values are count of ID's in each country/group.

I wish to add to the pivot percentage columns for each group.
It should display the percentage of the total in the source table.
If I hide some groups/countries then the total percentage will not be 100%.

I tried to add calculated field in which I divide the count of ID's to total ID's 
but it did not work.

How can I do it ?

Thank you

[Example File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pDqYKltOZpI0MQaZRm3c-NzvxRv21GUm/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What version of Excel do  you have? Do you have Power Pivot available? If not, you'll need to add a column to your source data that you can sum as a counter (i.e. a column with 1 for each row).

Comment: I can't use power pivot in this solution, I have a column with unique serial number. It is enoght? If not - I can add a column with the constant 1 for each row. Can you please show me on the example file what should I do in order to solve it? Thank you

Comment: You can actually do the first part by just adding the counting field to the table again and choosing to show values as % of grand total, but you can't get the grand total to be less than 100% when the data is filtered.

Comment: Thank you. This is my problem I need to show in the pivot values in percentage (% of source and not of pivot grand total so it will be less than 100% in case of filtering.

Comment: I don't believe you can do that in a pivot table without Power Pivot.